# Hosting multiple static Instances in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I need to host two servers, serving differ subdomains of the same server. in two different machine, say S1 and S2 with Nginx running in one of the servers say S1, load balancing both S1 and S2. I want to redirect to different static files for the subdomains which were in different machines.

How to configure the nginx to redirect to a static file on a different machine?

```
  server {
            server_name s1.example.com;
            listen 80;
            location / {
                    root /var/www/html/static/
            }
   }

   server {
            server_name s2.example.com;
            listen 80;
            location / {
                    root /var/www/html/static1/
            }
   }
```

The above is in case of same machine.

Comment: how you decide which files goes to which server?

Comment: with the subdomain mapping

Comment: Can you elaborate in your post with an example?